# Add email to image

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

is it possible to create an overlay image function so that when clicked on it opens outlook
The image is in a container and it represents a background

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="main_image"></div>
    <img class="overlay_image">
    <div id="overlay_image"></div>
    <p class="header">FAe</p>
    <p class="header2">Contact</p>
    <p class="header3">02 44</p>
</div>

     
    </div>
    </body>
```

CSS

```
#container{
    position: relative;
    width: 30cm;
    height: 7cm;
}
#main_image{
    width: 30cm;
    height: 7cm;
    background-image: url(Banner%20background.png);
}
#overlay_image{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 90px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url(Send%20mail.png);
    background-size: 186px auto;
    /* [disabled]background-position: 51% 11%; */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.header {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
    font-size: 126px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    position: relative;
    left: -100px;
    bottom: 350px;
}
.header2 {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    position: relative;
    left: -99px;
    top: -621px;
}

.header3 {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    position: relative;
    left: -200px;
    top: -656px;
}
```

I tried to just put an image with a href , but then the background disappears around one of the headers[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjYJR.png)
I would like when 'send an email' is clicked that Outlook opens with the mail address of my service here

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<body>

    <div id="container">
      <div id="main_image"></div>
        
       <a href="mailto:youremail@example.org"><img id="overlay_image"></a>
        <p class="header">FAe</p>
        <p class="header2">Contact</p>
        <p class="header3">02 44</p>
    </div>
    
    
         
      
 </body>
```

Note that overlay_image is defined with an ID in your css. So calling it as a regular css class won't work.